# OpenOPC for Python 3.4

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, opc

I'm currently using openOPC for python 2.7, I would like to know if is it possible to convert the library to 3.4, I've tried using 2to3 but it didn't work properly, all the versions available only work on python 2, so I'm stucked.
I've tried as well looking for another library with OPC-DA connection, but with no success.
Have anyone tried to use OpenOPC successfully in Python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/ya-mouse/openopc) project on github adapts OpenOPC for Python 3.4 and newer. Try that.

Comment: I've tried it before but I've just realized that I wasn't refering the folder that the files were, so I thought that it didn't work in Python 3.4. Anyway thanks it worked now!

Answer (score 0):

[Download OpenOPC-Python](https://pypi.org/project/OpenOPC-Python3x/#files)

```
pip install OpenOPC-Python3x
pip install OpenOPC-Python3x
pip install OpenOPC-Python3x
pip install OpenOPC-Python3x
```